# Downloading problems with android 4.0/ 4.1.2

Tags: java, android, download, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am having a problem with android 4.0 or higher when, I'm Trying to download a file from a URL, It works fine in android Galaxy Y 2.3 / 2.2 but when I use the same code for Galaxy S3(4.1.2) the download starts but it doesn't finish.

Code:

```
 public void update() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Método para fazer a atualização iniciado.");
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Conectando com a internet...");
        URL url = new URL(
                url);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        Log.d(TAG, "Iniciando arquivo...");
        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/test/Update/";
        File file = new File(PATH);
        file.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(file, "test.apk");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        Log.d(TAG, "Iniciando Stream...");
        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        Log.d(TAG, "Iniciando o download...");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Iniciando instalador...");
        final Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(PATH + "test.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(promptInstall);
        Log.d(TAG, "Instalador iniciado com sucesso!");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Malformed URL. Mensagem: " + e.getMessage()
                + " Causa: " + e.getCause());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException. Mensagem: " + e.getMessage() + " Causa: "
                + e.getCause());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception. Mensagem: " + e.getMessage() + " Causa: "
                + e.getCause());
    }
}
```

Obs:There is no Error, It just start the download and stop it.
File size : 126,188 bytes and in the Galaxy S3 6,403 bytes

Comment: From the documentation; _HttpURLConnection uses the GET method by default. It will use POST if setDoOutput(true) has been called._ You could try removing ``c.setDoOutput(true)`` line since you're not posting anything and see if it fixed the problem with closing the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make your request.

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely doing a network operation on the main thread, StrictMode won't allow that.